# The range of a function $f : n^+ \to \omega$ has a largest element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am completely lost on this question:

> Assume that $n \in \omega$  and $f: n^{+} \rightarrow \omega$. Show that $ran\ f$ has a largest element.

What I don't understand is that we are given no information about $f$, and $\omega$ (the set of all natural numbers) has no largest number. I am deeply confused about something here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. The point is that given any arbitrary function from a positive integer into $\omega$, then the range of the function, which is a subset of $\omega$, will have a maximal element.

In particular, this means that there is no surjection from any integer onto $\omega$.

Comment: Here is one attempt I have so far but I am not sure if I am begging the question.

We use induction. Considering $f(0)$, we know that $f(0)$ is a single-ton set so it trivially has a largest element. Assuming $f(k) holds$, we simply consider $f(k) \cup f(k^{+})$. Since $f(k^{+})$ is a single-ton set (since $f$ is a function), we know that $f(k) \cup f(k^{+})$ has a largest element since the union of two sets with a largest element has a largest element.

Comment: Well, it seems that you got it right. I'm not 100% sure about your use of $f(k)$ and such. It's not clear if you mean that as the image of the set, or the image of a particular element. In the latter case, how do you know that $f(k)$ is the maximum of $f$ restricted to $\{0,\ldots,k\}$?